# mystery symbol on page

Tags: html

I have looked at the markup for this page forever and I can't for the life of me figure out why there is a "greater than" symbol visible on this page in between the navigation and the main content.  I keep staring at it because it bugs me but I don't see the mistake.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Page: http://cdaniels75.github.io/210/schedule.html

Comment: `<tr><td>33</td> <td>04.28</td>><td>FINALS WEEK<br />` Extra `>` here. It gets moved to the top of the table because text is not valid inside a table.

Comment: It's between `<div id="schedule">` and `<table>`

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I was focusing on the area where it was appearing on the screen and I wasn't finding it! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 57 of the source is this:

```
<tr><td>33</td> <td>04.28</td>><td>FINALS WEEK<br /><h6><a
```

Notice the extra `>` between `<td>`s.

That said you have a large number of markup errors on this page, like unclosed `<a>` tags and such. Run it through the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://cdaniels75.github.io/210/schedule.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for finding it.  Yeah, I am sure it doesn't validate.  I just threw this up quickly to give my students a pretty schedule...

Answer (score 0):

in your favorite browser with dev tools installed, right-click on the ">" and select Inspect element (or similar) from the popup menu...